Why do I get different results for getSymbols on two identical machines, one with no error, the other with a curl error?
I have two Windows 10 machines, both connected to the internet on the same wifi. Both running RStudio.  On Machine 1 after installing the quantmod library I do this:
x <- getSymbols("VTI",src="yahoo")
This works fine and x becomes "VTI".
On Machine 2, I run the same code and I get the following:
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(cu, handle = h) :
Error while processing content unencoding: invalid block type
I've also tried Machine 2 with a different wifi and get the same error.  I have also rebooted Machine 2 and restarted RStudio, but continue to get the same error.  I have also turned off the firewall in Machine 2 and continue to get the same error since some commentators on a similar problem have suggested it might be a firewall or internet problem. Until today Machine 2 ran this code with no problems so I am stumped at what might have changed.
On a second try I also get the following:
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(cu, handle = h) :
Error while processing content unencoding: too many length or distance symbols

maybe share the R.version and RStudio.version outputs of both machines

Was an automatic Windows Update installed on machine 2 recently? Maybe wind-back any install and re-try. Also, double check that outputs of sessionInfo() are the same.
